# What Does the Normalization Factor Mean in the AdaBoost Algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, distribution, descriptive-statistics, boosting

I am studying the AdaBoost algorithm. The update rule for a weak hypothesis is:

$Dt+1(i) = Dt(i)exp(−αtyiht(xi))/zt $

where $zt$ is a normalization factor chosen so that $Dt+1$ is a distribution.

What does the 'normalization factor' mean? Could I have an explanation with an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **normalization factor**  is used to reduce any probability function to a probability density function with total probability of one. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant).

Say your *unnormalized* value is `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2]`. You normalize it by dividing it by $z_t=0.1+0.2+0.3+0.2=0.8$, therefore get the *normalized* value `[0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.25]` which sums up to 1..